# How to trigger click event for list of anchors by loop - in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make our-team slider for Angular app. **my scenario** is to get a list of anchor elements and loop through them with a bit of delay before triggering clicks (each click would call the next slider).

Next will be shown my JS code => that I want to convert to Angular.

Source code provided on [codepen](https://codepen.io/MedooEgy/pen/JjENaLZ?editors=0010)

note: first two slides are empty for some reason it's okay
**HTML**

```
<div id="slider">
  
<div id="0" class="SlideContainer">
.. empty
  <a href="#1">Click Me 0</a>
</div>
  
<div id="1" class="SlideContainer">
.. empty
  <a href="#2">Click Me 1</a>
</div>
  
<!-- angular ngFor starts from here => -->
<div id="2" class="SlideContainer">
  <div class="img">
<img src="https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/11-112605_punk-cat-berkley-cats-illustrations.png">
</div>
  <a href="#3">Click Me 2</a>
</div>

  ......... etc

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slider {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 500px;
  padding: .5%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.SlideContainer{ 
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 99% ;
  width: 33%;
  margin: .5% 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.SlideContainer a{
  display: none;
}

.img {
  overflow: hidden; 
  max-width:200px;
  max-height:200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.img img{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var i = 3;                
var listA = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var timer;

function SlideLoop() { 
  timer = setTimeout(() => {     
    listA[i].click();                 
    if (i < 12) 
       {i++}
    else
       {i = 1}  
    SlideLoop();
  }, 2000);
};

SlideLoop();
```

Now all I need to apply the same JS scenario in Angular TS. And here is my attempt in Angular

**TS**

```
constructor(
  private slidesHref: ElementRef,
  @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: HTMLDocument
  ) {}

  // attempt 1
  elements = this.slidesHref.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.SlideContainer a');
  // attempt 2
  elem = this._document.querySelectorAll('.SlideContainer a');
  
  ngOnInit(){
    this.elements[4].click();
    this.elems.forEach(e => e.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')));
}
```

Again: I need to get that list of Anchors and iterate through them using loop and trigger click as displayed in the JS code example but using Angular(TS).

Comment: you just want to replicate your js code to angular.. is it?

Comment: @RaishavHanspal do you mean to execute the function in ngOnInit? It makes post back with each loop

Comment: no no that's not what I meant although I have a workaround. You can maintain an array ActiveArray of three elements (that must be visible). You can use setInterval in ngAfterViewInit() to alter the ActiveArray. and using *ngIf="ActiveArray.includes(current element)" directive can show/hide the required.